# Weird lines on screen – possibly graphics card issue

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, cpu, hdmi, intel-graphics

When Windows boots to the login screen, my whole screen goes fuzzy with lines and weird pixels all over moving about looking glitchy. When I updated my graphics card to the default "Microsoft Basic Display Adapter" it stopped; however, I can't use my laptop properly because I can't disable the auto brightness. Also, I cannot use the HDMI output. When I update to the proper driver, "Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000", I instantly get these horrible lines and pixels jittering everywhere. When I use the HDMI output on my screen with this same driver, there aren't any lines.

It has been like this for a while, but before it was only a few subtle horizontal lines. Now it is as if my whole screen is going crazy. I think I first started seeing symptoms of this around 4 months ago, but only yesterday did it suddenly go from mild to crazy.

Is my graphics card dying?

If so, why does it affect only the laptop screen and not the HDMI output?

- Laptop is Samsung 700t
- Windows 10 operating system (same problem for 8.1)
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3317U CPU @ 1.70GHz, 1701 MHz, 2 Core(s), 2 Logical Processor(s)

Here is a screenshot of HWmonitor if it helps:
      [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

It probably is the graphics card.  Internally the screen is probably wired to a DisplayPort connector and it may be something with the LVDS channel that's gone wonky.  It would explain why it doesn't happen on HDMI.  But the fact that it only happens when using the native driver definitely points to hardware.  The Microsoft Basic driver does not have any 3D acceleration whatsoever, so it would not provoke the issue.

No matter how you slice it, your hardware is likely bad.  I hope it's still under warranty.

Comment: Thanks for the response, do you know if its possible to replace it or even repair it?

Comment: Possibly, but the GPU is integrated into the CPU, so IF the processor is socketed it's possible to replace it.  But you'd be replacing the entire CPU. Many computers nowadays are soldering the CPU directly to the motherboard though. If that's your case then no, you can't replace it.

Comment: The Samsung 700t is a tablet device, it will not have a replaceable processor.

Answer (score 0):

The information supplied lacks the proper diagnostic steps to be declared a graphics processor related issue.

If the 'static' appears when the desktop is still, it is very unlikely to be GPU related.  Make sure that your refresh rate frequency is set correctly before continuing.

Ordinarily you can diagnose this by opening and closing the laptop lid in small increments to see if it affects the static on the screen.  If so the problem lies in the LCD panel wiring.  The cables used (sometimes flex-ribbon, sometimes a taped bundle of wires) can wear out, or even come loose from their sockets.  The problem you describe has the exact same symptoms, especially since HDMI works fine (a bad GPU would likely cause artifacts regardless of display).  The problem can be intermittent, and even appear to depend on software installed.  As your laptop is actually a tablet, you can instead try gently flexing or tapping your device, as it has no moving parts susceptible to percussive recalibration.  If doing so does does affect the static, you can replace the connector cable, or the LCD panel if required.

The HWMonitor info you provided is in perfect order.  If 67 is the average high your device is used to, it is unlikely that your 3317U has suffered heat damage causing GPU failure.

You can further diagnose your issue by performing a video benchmark.  If the GPU is to blame, when the GPU is under load and heats up drastically more artifacts will present themselves.  You can use the winsat/WEI built into windows Vista and newer, or my recommendation of 3Dmark, link following.

http://www.3dmark.com

My assessment of the information you've provided is that the fault lies in the hardware level of the display itself, be it connector cables or LCD components.